# Question about trees

Tags: graph-theory

When must an edge for a connected simple graph appear in every spanning tree for this graph?

I would have thought it was the midpoint of the longest simple path in the graph. However, there would then be another way to connect the graph, so location of vertices doesn't matter.

Comment: If and only if it is a cut edge. I.e removal of the graph disconnects it.

Comment: I'll take that as an answer @TheNumber23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, If and only of it is a cut edge.